# Do/while loop not functioning correctly

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem getting my do/while loop to function properly.
This program runs good the first go-around, but when i enter 'y' when it asks if i would like to "tell more" the program just asks the user the question (not allowing me to enter a string) and then couts the statements. What am I doing wrong? and how do i get it to function properly?

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, numspaces = 0;
    char nextChar;
    string trimstring;
    string uc, rev;
    string answer;
    char temp;
    cout << "\n\n John Acosta"
    <<" Exercise 1\n"
    << "\n\n This program will take your string, count the number\n"
    << " of chars and words, UPPERCASE your string, and reverse your string.";

    string astring;
    do {
        cout << "\n\nTell me something about yourself: ";
        getline (cin, astring);

        trimstring = astring;
        uc = astring;
        rev = astring;

        for (i=0; i<int(astring.length()); i++)
        {
            nextChar = astring.at(i); // gets a character
            if (isspace(astring[i]))
                numspaces++;
        }


        trimstring.erase(remove(trimstring.begin(),trimstring.end(),' '),trimstring.end());
        transform(uc.begin(), uc.end(),uc.begin(), ::toupper);

        for (i=0; i<rev.length()/2; i++)
        {
            temp = rev[i];
            rev[i] = rev[rev.length()-i-1];
            rev[rev.length()-i-1] = temp;
        }

        cout << "\n\tYou Entered: " << astring
        << "\n\tIt has "<<trimstring.length()
        << " chars and "<<numspaces+1
        << " words."
        << "\n\tUPPERCASE: "<<uc
        << "\n\tReversed: "<<rev
        << "\n\n";


        cout<<"\n\nwant to tell me more? Enter \"y\" for YES and \"n\" for NO\n\n";
        cin>>answer;
        cout<<"\n";

    } while(answer == "y");                 //contiue loop while answer is 'y'; stop when 'n'

    {
        cout <<"\n Thanks. Goodbye!\n";     //when loop is done
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For a start, I would put some code in to check if answer == y or Y (I leave it to you to look up how to do that) because if the user's got caps lock on, the do/while loop will fail at the moment.

Comment: Reduce this to a [short self contained correct example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input operator `>>` works like this: First it skips whitespace, if any; Then it reads the string until it reaches the next whitespace, in your case the newline after the `'y'`. This newline is then left in the stream so when you at the beginning of the loop do `getline` you get that newline left after the `"y"`.

You can remove this by using the [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) function:

```
cout<<"\n\nwant to tell me more? Enter \"y\" for YES and \"n\" for NO\n\n";
cin>>answer;
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
cout<<"\n";
```

Comment: thank you! I actually inserted cin.ignore() underneath:                                                                   cout << "\n\nTell me something about yourself: ";
        getline (cin, astring); for some crazy reason!